# How to properly check the background color of cell using EPPlus?

Tags: c#, epplus

W want to check if background color of cell is yellow and **if cell has background color at all**...

```
workSheet.Cells[rCnt, 1].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Rgb ==
```

What next?

Comment: What have you tried? That code is what looks to be 1/2 of an if statement

Answer (score 1):

Background Color has an **RGB** property and that's what you can use to get the value of color that you want. This is the code

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(excelFile))
{
    ExcelWorkbook workbook = package.Workbook;

    ExcelWorksheet currentWorksheet = workbook.Worksheets.First();

    ExcelRange theCell = currentWorksheet.Cells[8, 1];
    if (theCell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Rgb == Color.Yellow.A.ToString("X2") + Color.Yellow.R.ToString("X2") + Color.Yellow.G.ToString("X2") + Color.Yellow.B.ToString("X2"))
    {
      String getValue = theCell.Value.ToString();
    }

}
```

or you can use **function** to return the **HexValue** like

```
if (theCell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Rgb == ColorHexValue(Color.Yellow))
      {
        String getValue = theCell.Value.ToString();
      }
```

The **function** to return the Hex Value:

```
   private String ColorHexValue(System.Drawing.Color C)
    {
        return C.A.ToString("X2") + C.R.ToString("X2") + C.G.ToString("X2") + C.B.ToString("X2");
    }
```

if you don't want to use function, you can do simply by using code below.

```
Color.Yellow.ToArgb().ToString("X").
```

It is the exact same output. Make it an extension method if you need even more convenience

Answer (score 1):

For anyone getting here, since I had my round of fun with EPPlus and I wasn't satisfied with the answers above:

```
cell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.LookupColor()
```

returns #AARRGGBB color (I.E. red is #FFFF0000). The part you're interesdted in is probably the last 6 digits.

You then can probably match it with OP ColorHexValue func, or just compare the string with an IF.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do with it but here's an example that will store the values in a Dictionary containing the cell name and the C# color if the color is yellow.

Base Spreadsheet Data

[image: Spreadsheet Data]

```
    //open file into p
using (var p = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(@"c:\FooFolder\Foo.xlsx")))
{
ExcelWorkbook wb = p.Workbook;
ExcelWorksheet ew = wb.Worksheets.First();

//create a dictionary to store your cell colors
Dictionary<string, Color> cellColors = new Dictionary<string, Color>();

//define your rows and columns to loop through
int rowNum = ew.Dimension.Start.Row;
int rowEnd = ew.Dimension.End.Row;
int cellBegin = ew.Dimension.Start.Column;
int cellEnd = ew.Dimension.End.Column;

//loop through all of the rows
for (int y = rowNum; y<= rowEnd; y++)
{
    //loop through the cells in each row
    for(int x= cellBegin; x<= cellEnd; x++)
    {
        //get the range of the current cll
        ExcelRange currentCell = ew.Cells[y, x];
        //get the rgb string value of the background color 
        string rgb = ew.Cells[y,x].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Rgb;
        //create variable to convert rgb color to C# color
        System.Drawing.Color CurrentCellColor;

        //if rgb is null then there is no background color so default to white.
        if (rgb != null)
            CurrentCellColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" + rgb);
        else
            CurrentCellColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");

        //add to your dictionary if is yellow
        if (rgb != null && CurrentCellColor.Equals(Color.Yellow))
            cellColors.Add(currentCell.Address, CurrentCellColor);
    }
}
p.Save();
}
```

The dictionary ends with 2 values in it.
[image: Dictionary]

Answer (score 0):

Liquid Core provides a good approach for this problem.  In this example, cell "A2" contains an unknown color used in an existing worksheet that I want to use to set the background color of a given row, i.  As for the OP request to determine if the cell has no background at all, change A2 to point to a cell without a background color, and check the value in the rgb string variable.  For people new to EPPlus, you must set Fill.PatternType before calling SetColor.

```
string rgb = targetSheet.worksheet.Cells["A2"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.LookupColor();
targetSheet.worksheet.Row(i).Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
targetSheet.worksheet.Row(i).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(ColorTranslator.FromHtml(rgb));
```